# Difference Jekyll local server and github

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll (on GitHub Pages) for my blog.

When I run Jekyll on a local server, it looks OK:

[image]

But when I push the site to GitHub, the code section is broken:

[image]

What is the difference between the environments? This is my config file:

```yaml
timezone:    America/New_York
locale:      en_US
future:      true
highlighter: rouge
markdown:    kramdown
gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed
permalink:   /:categories/:title/
paginate: 5
float_share: true
kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  enable_coderay: true
  coderay:
    coderay_line_numbers: nil
    coderay_line_numbers_start: 1
    coderay_tab_width: 4
    coderay_bold_every: 10
    coderay_css: class
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is a [jekyll-kramdown rendering issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3724#issuecomment-183603945), and see if the following [config file](https://github.com/acemod/ACE3/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml#L26-L28) works better.

For those code block, use the syntax recommended in "[Creating and highlighting code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/)"

> For example, to syntax highlight Ruby code:

````
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: timezone:    America/New_York
locale:      en_US
future:      true
highlighter: rouge
markdown:    kramdown
gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed

# https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Permalinks
permalink:   /:categories/:title/

# Amount of post to show on home page
paginate: 5

Comment: This is my config file. But I can't find any problem with my config file. Originally, My config file work well in github. But suddenlly this problem happen even if I didn't change anything.

Comment: @JinyongJeongSteve you can edit your question, with the content of your config file: that will be easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. I add part of config file in my question